# How to write data in JSON file in the EJS template file

Tags: javascript, json

What I want to do is saving the IP address in a json file.

```
    <script>
    function getIP(json) {
      alert(json.ip);
      //I want the "json.ip" data to appear in a JSON file I called ip.JSON
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by you want to “write” the data? Is it simply just writing the JSON response to the DOM?

Comment: I want the IP address to be saved in the JSON file I created that's all.

Comment: In the js file what I do is fs.writeFileSync("ip.JSON", data). Here in the EJS file, it differs I think.